# getattribute in VBA unable to compare value in recordset

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, web-scraping, automation

I am working on an automation project for my organization where I require VBA to check a checkbox on a webpage. I am able to check the box if I hard code in the value of the checkbox which I retrieved from the HTML source code. The value however does not stay static - the value is to be derived from a recordset table. All of this works in Access VBA.

This is the code where I hard code in the value - this works perfectly.

```
Set search1 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("check")
For Each e In search1
    If (e.getAttribute("value") = "2207891") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
```

But when the same value comes in from a recordset, I do not get the checkbox to be checked. What is it that I am overlooking?

```
Set search1 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("check")
For Each e In search1
    If (e.getAttribute("value") = rsextract!MATCH_ID) Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
```

I did a msgbox rsextract!MATCH_ID before the loop to check whether the value is the same one I'm looking for and the value is correct. I tried placing rsextract!MATCH_ID in "" but that didn't help either. I'm clearly overlooking something but I do not know what. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following which uses an attribute selector and concatenation to target. No loop.

```
ie.document.querySelector(".check[value='" & cstr(rsextract!MATCH_ID) & "']").click
```

Comment: Thanks a ton QHarr, this is what differentiates a good programmer and me! Stay blessed.

Comment: @ReninMathew Just lots of practice here. :-)